# Dual Boot Ubuntu 14.04 after windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot

After today's disaster I'm not trying to dual boot ubuntu 14.04 with windows 10 again.I wasted a day and a half trying to get back to where I started.
1. Nothing comes up asking if I want to dual boot, so only alternative is to opt for the 'something else' option
2. Following instructions very very carefully I created the root directory followed by the swap and the home, all of which were accepted so all I had to do was to install ??
It soon became apparent that ubuntu didn't recognise that I had a windows application and selfishly just installed ubuntu by itself !!
What a mess, and that having read the various answers here, I'm not really any the wiser, so unless anyone can give an answer that doesn't require a degree in IT, then with much regret I 'm  going to ditch ubuntu for good, or any other distro for that matter.
Sorry to sound so negative.
Peter

Comment: We'll need a little more information to offer any constructive advice.  Is this a UEFI machine?  Is the disk partitioning gpt or msdos? Did you shrink the Windows partitions from within Windows and then run checkdsk a few times?  Did you change the Windows power options to shutdown instead of sleep?  What instructions did you follow? ...

Comment: That's because windows 10 selfishly has a feature called fast boot that puts the system into a hibernated state *even when you choose to shut down the system properly*. *This* is the problem and *this* is why ubuntu didn't recognize the windows partition because windows is in a hibernated state. You need to go into windows, disable fast boot, shut down windows *properly and fully* and then install ubuntu.

Comment: @ubfan1 Thanks for the reply. I was NOT doing this on a UEFI machine and was formatted in gpt.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the instructions for doing the low level work that you describe (partition management) strongly encourages backing up your important data.

Based on your description it appears that you have deleted your Windows installation.  If it weren't deleted after the current Ubuntu installation that you have, you would see the option to boot either into Windows or into Ubuntu.  If you had other recognizable OS installations you would also have a grub menu item to chose those.

Since, in your description you have said that you (inadvertently) have a Ubuntu only installation.  You can boot then run this in a terminal.

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Grub will see all your OS installations and in your next boot you will have an option to boot into either.

If you don't have Windows as a boot option in the grub menu you can install Windows, then run the steps below to install Grub so that you can have the option to choose which OS to boot to.

While in Ubuntu, launch gnome-disk-utility to check all your available drive partitions.  You can use this utility to mount the various partitions to look for any of your Windows data, or to identify a partition for installing Windows.

You can also use gparted.  You can either install it with `$ sudo apt-get install gparted` and run it from Ubuntu or you can boot to the Live Ubuntu install disk and run it from there.

Then from `gparted` you can create the partition or size your partitions to accommodate the installations you want... similar to what you have described you've been doing... be sure to back up your important data before modifying the partitions.

Once you reinstall Windows, you will no longer be able to boot to Grub.  Windows will install it's own boot manager.  You can reinstall grub with the following steps:

**How to repair Ubuntu after installing Windows**
(You can check your partitions by running `$ sudo fdisk -l`)

```
1) boot to the Ubuntu installation disk
2) Run the "Try Ubuntu" option
3) Bring up a terminal (Launch search "terminal")
4) Run these commands (exactly):    
    a) sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt  # Make "X" the partition that has Ubuntu installed (i.e. /dev/sda2).
    b) 
    c) sudo chroot /mnt
    d) update-grub
    e) if no errors skip this "e" section
        grub-install /dev/sdX (x is the hard drive that has linux installed (i.e. /dev/sda)
        update-grub
5) Reboot the system
```